# commerce userpoints discount is not working

Tags: commerce, userpoints

I'm using [drupal commerce userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_userpoints) module for discount using userpoints on checkout page but that is not working when I click on 'Apply Credits'.

Can you please guide me in this, how to configure properly from admin, I followed directions but maybe I did something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Before anybody can help you on finding out what you may have done wrong, YOU need to improve your question to explain what you did. This also avoids guessing like "you did install the [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module, right?"